# Numbering of related Bible books

Tags: numbers

Related (multi-volume?) books of the Bible are numbered with consecutive arabic numerals placed before a common title, which are read as ordinals (e.g., “1 Samuel” (“first Samuel”) and “2 Samuel” (“second Samuel”)).  Why are they numbered this way?  Is anything else that use this format?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you don’t have an answer, that’s alright.

Comment: The formal title would be "The First Book of Samuel" - "1 Samuel" or "Samuel 1" are used for convenience.

Comment: @KateBunting  Thanks.  Is this usage documented somewhere?  Like, is it okay if I use this format to number a series of things in a non-religious context?

Comment: You mean putting the numeral first? In most contexts, e.g. chapters in an ordinary book, the numeral goes afterwards (Chapter One/1/I).

Comment: In the UK at least military regiments and sub units of regiments are often referred to in this way. [This article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/39th_Regiment_Royal_Artillery) discussing the now disbanded 39th Regiment of the Royal Artillery also known as "Three Nine Regiment Royal Artillery" gives copious examples. Like the books of the Bible the form is a shortened version of the full name of the regiment, battery and so on.

Comment: @KateBunting But ordinal numbers go first: First Grade, Second Grade, ...

Comment: I do agree with Hot Licks and since you're here, where is your research? What other systems of classification or numeration have you considered, what have you ruled out and why?